# what would be $F=\bigcup_{i=1}^N [a_i,b_i]$ in $m(E\Delta F)\leq \varepsilon$ if $E=\mathbb Q$?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Refer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476464/e-measurable-then-there-is-f-bigcup-i-1nq-i-such-that-me-delta-f-var/1511210#1511210), what would be such an $F$ if $E=\mathbb Q$ ? I mean, $\mathbb Q$ has measure null and thus the measure is finite. Therefore, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $[a_1,b_1],...,[a_N,b_N]$ s.t. $$m\left(E\Delta \bigcup_{i=1}^N [a_i,b_i]\right)<\varepsilon.$$
But I can't find them if $E=\mathbb Q$. What would be such cubes $[a_i,b_i]$ if $E=\mathbb Q$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$
  \mu(A\Delta \Bbb Q) = \mu(A\setminus \Bbb Q) + \mu(\Bbb Q\setminus A) = \mu(A) + 0.
$$

Comment: why $\mu(A\backslash Q)=\mu(A)$ ? If $A$ is an interval that contain $\mathbb  Q$, then $A=\mathbb R$... so $\mu(A\backslash \mathbb Q)=\mu(A)$ look strange to me... And if $A$ is a finit interval, how can $A$ approximate $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: @idm $A\setminus \Bbb Q$ are all irrational numbers in $A$, to take set differences we do not have to have set inclusion